# Is there any connection string parser in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a connection string and I want to be able to peek out for example "Data Source".
Is there a parser, or do I have to search the string?

Answer (score 354, accepted):

Yes, there's the [**`System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) class.

> The DbConnectionStringBuilder class
>   provides the base class from which the
>   strongly typed connection string
>   builders (SqlConnectionStringBuilder,
>   OleDbConnectionStringBuilder, and so
>   on) derive. The connection string
>   builders let developers
>   programmatically create syntactically
>   correct connection strings, and parse
>   and rebuild existing connection
>   strings.

The subclasses of interest are:

```
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionStringBuilder
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionStringBuilder
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
```

---

For example, to "peek out the Data Source" from a SQL-server connection string, you can do:

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
var dataSource = builder.DataSource;
```

Comment: The base class `DbConnectionStringBuilder` has generic processing features that can be used without using subclasses: `if (builder.TryGetValue("Password", out var pwd)) {
                    string decrypted = SomehowDecrypt(pwd);
                    builder["Password"] = decrypted; }`

Answer (score 47):

There are vendor specific connection string builders from various providers like `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`, `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`, `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder` etc (unfortunately there is no public interface from MS this time). Otherwise you have [DbProviderFactory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.createconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) which will give you an alternate way to write it provider-agnostic way. You would need to specify provider in config file and have the right version of dll available. For eg.,

```
var c = "server=localhost;User Id=root;database=ppp";
var f = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient"); //your provider
var b = f.CreateConnectionStringBuilder();
b.ConnectionString = c;
var s = b["data source"];
var d = b["database"];
```

I had once written manual parsing for myself which did not give me any trouble. It would be trivial to extend this to give info on other parameters (right now its only for simple things like db name, data source, username and password). Like this or so:

```
static readonly string[] serverAliases = { "server", "host", "data source", "datasource", "address", 
                                           "addr", "network address" };
static readonly string[] databaseAliases = { "database", "initial catalog" };
static readonly string[] usernameAliases = { "user id", "uid", "username", "user name", "user" };
static readonly string[] passwordAliases = { "password", "pwd" };

public static string GetPassword(string connectionString)
{
    return GetValue(connectionString, passwordAliases);
}

public static string GetUsername(string connectionString)
{
    return GetValue(connectionString, usernameAliases);
}

public static string GetDatabaseName(string connectionString)
{
    return GetValue(connectionString, databaseAliases);
}

public static string GetServerName(string connectionString)
{
    return GetValue(connectionString, serverAliases);
}

static string GetValue(string connectionString, params string[] keyAliases)
{
    var keyValuePairs = connectionString.Split(';')
                                        .Where(kvp => kvp.Contains('='))
                                        .Select(kvp => kvp.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2))
                                        .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp[0].Trim(),
                                                      kvp => kvp[1].Trim(),
                                                      StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    foreach (var alias in keyAliases)
    {
        string value;
        if (keyValuePairs.TryGetValue(alias, out value))
            return value;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

For this you don't need anything special in config file, or any dll at all. `Contains` in `Where` clause is important only if you need to bypass poorly formatted connectionstrings like `server = localhost;pp;` where `pp` adds to nothing. To behave like normal builders (which would explode in these cases) change the `Where` to

```
.Where(kvp => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(kvp))
```

Comment: @Icarus not really since the dictionary's key comparer is `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`. See the `ToDictionary` overload

Comment: Yep, you are right, I just wrote a quick test. Will delete my original comment since it's wrong.

Comment: Your GetValue() method will not work in cases where for example the user has a `';'` or an `'='` in their password. I had written a similar implementation and learned that it doesn't work the hard way. Gosh, connection string parsing is actually a lot harder than I thought!

Comment: @Joshua I hope you're talking about the manual parsing part. Please take answers here as a starting point that could be worked on rather than foolproof and battle-tested solutions. I hope they are more valuable than comments that leave no information. You're also free to downvote. As far as I know, what needs to be further done is adhere to parsing standards. MS has one on msdn and it's been long in my mind to ammend. If only we all had time. '@'all please bear in mind the edge cases, esp one in Philip Atz's comment.

Comment: @nawfal: I came around and left an answer once I solved it.

Comment: Split(';')  - password may content those 4 symbols { ; " '

Answer (score 25):

Here's a couple lines of code that would parse any connection string into a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> connStringParts = connString.Split(';')
    .Select(t => t.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2))
    .ToDictionary(t => t[0].Trim(), t => t[1].Trim(), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

And then you can access any part:

```
string dataSource = connStringParts["Data Source"];
```

Comment: Smart, the only thing I would change would be include `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to the first split as it will cause a `IndexOutOfRange` exception if there is a trailing `;`

Comment: This works, but the connection string builders are more robust. Code like this will throw low-level exceptions instead of more meaningful parsing errors in the case of invalid connection strings.

Comment: This helped me parse an ADO connection string so I could build an equivalent `SqlConnection` with the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`.

Comment: Some caveats here. Connection string values can be enclosed in quotes, for example.

Comment: Won't work if parameter value contains ';' caracter for exemple Passwod='Pa$$w0rd;'

Answer (score 19):

I didn't really like all the answers here. So here is what I found.

### [DbConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

You can use built-in `DbConnectionStringBuilder` directly:

```
var builder = new System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;login=sa;pass=awesomeness";

var server = builder["server"];
var login = builder["login"];
var pass = builder["pass"];
```

Comment: One-liner version: 
`var server = new DbConnectionStringBuilder { ConnectionString = settings.ConnectionString }["server"]`

Answer (score 7):

You want to use [DbProviderFactory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder ()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.createconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) which provides you a connection string builder/parser specific to your connector, but does not require you to use any connector specific classes.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx)
Unfortunately you will have to use a DB specific ConnectionStringBuilder as the connection strings differ.

Answer (score 5):

Yes , You can do this using ConnectionStringBuilder Classes.
Here is the list of available DbConnectionStringBuilder implementations for standard data providers:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionStringBuilder
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionStringBuilder
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
```

here are sample example of parse connection string and display it's elements.

```
 string conString = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;" +
                        "Database=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
                        "Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=15;Connection Reset=True;" +
                        "Connection Lifetime=600;";
    // Parse the SQL Server connection string and display it's properties

    SqlConnectionStringBuilder objSB1 = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(conString);
    Response.Write("<b>Parsed SQL Connection String Parameters:</b>");
    Response.Write(" <br/>  Database Source = " + objSB1.DataSource);
    Response.Write(" <br/>  Database = " + objSB1.InitialCatalog);
    Response.Write(" <br/>  Use Integrated Security = " + objSB1.IntegratedSecurity);
    Response.Write(" <br/>  Min Pool Size = " + objSB1.MinPoolSize);
    Response.Write(" <br/>  Max Pool Size = " + objSB1.MaxPoolSize);
    Response.Write(" <br/>  Lifetime = " + objSB1.LoadBalanceTimeout);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use DbConnectionStringBuilder, and you don't need any specific provider:

The following code:

```
var cnstr = "Data Source=data source value;Server=ServerValue";
var builder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.ConnectionString = cnstr;
Console.WriteLine("Data Source: {0}", builder["Data Source"]);
Console.WriteLine("Server: {0}", builder["Server"]);
```

Outputs to console:

```
Data Source: data source value
Server: ServerValue
```

EDIT:

Since DbConnectionStringBuilder implements IDictionary you can enumerate the connection string parameters:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kv in builder)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", kv.Key, kv.Value);
}
```

Comment: This assumes you already know that the connection string has a "Data Source" value, etc., which isn't always true, as noted in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15529085/534109, above.

Comment: My answer addrees specifically what the op ask: 'I want to be able to peek out for example "Data Source"'

Comment: I edited it to show all connection string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

So I found all of the existing answers were more or less wrong. I ended up with the following trivial solution:

```
class ConnectionStringParser: DbConnectionStringBuilder {
    ConnectionStringParser(string c) { Connection = c; }
    public override bool ShouldSerialize(string keyword) => true;
}
```

The parser is in DbConnectionStringBuilder and pretty much easy to get at. The only silly thing we have to do is set ShouldSerialize to always return true to prevent losing components when trying to round trip arbitrary connection strings.

Comment: What was wrong with existing answers? Or what does your solution fix. Explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In general I use my own construct, as it's simple easy and don't have additional dependency

```cs
private Dictionary<string, string> ParseConnectionString(string stringData, char propDelim = ';', char kvDelim = '=')
{
            
    Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Array.ForEach<string>(stringData.Split(propDelim), s =>
    {
         if (s != null && s.Length != 0)
             keyValuePairs.Add(s.Split(kvDelim)[0], s.Split(kvDelim)[1]);
    });

     return keyValuePairs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a dotnet code lib [Sekvap](https://github.com/sandrock/Sekvap-dotnet) (nuget: [SrkSekvap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SrkSekvap/)) to parse this kind of string. It is not limited to connection strings as the general format can be used for many other usages.

The main difference is the ability to have a "main value" in front of the string; but it will parse connection strings as-is.

Also, the lib is very small and without dependencies. That may be an alternative to the other answers.