# asp.net to set a table backcolor dynamicaly based on the server in the SQL connectionstring

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<table style="width: 100%; background-color: #B5C7DE">
```

i have this table and want to change the background-color to be yellow if the server used int he SQL connection string is not 'pheddv20'

i am adding c# code to the page load event to check for this and run the dynamic logic. the connection string is held in the web.config as is typically seen...

whats the code look like for this type of action?

Comment: You can grab the value of a public property to set the back color, example <table style="background-color: <%= BackColor %>;">.  In order to do this, create a public property called BackColor and set the value in your load event.

Comment: I assume you have added runat="server" and id to this table tag so that you are able to access it in page load event. Right?

Comment: If your question is, how to get the server out of the connection string, the `DbConnectionStringBuilder` class is what you are searching for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804086/is-there-any-connection-string-parser-in-c/4804099#4804099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to mark the table with a css class:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .releasedata{background:red}
 .testdata{background:yellow}
</style>
<table class='<%= GetTableClassForEnvironment() %>'>...</table>
```

In your code behind you'd want to add the method

```
protected string GetTableClassForEnvironment()
{
/*
  parse environment string from web.config using ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx
*/
}
```

This wasn't in your post, but I'm guessing you want to have the table show up in different colors depending on the environment (ie. debug/release/qa).  You should look into using web.config transormations.  If you do that you can use conditional compilation statements in your code behind and you won't have to rely on web.config parsing.  So your method becomes

```
protected string GetTableClassForEnvironment()
{
#IF DEBUG
 return "releasedata"
#ELSE
 return "testdata"
#END IF

}
```

Answer (score 0):

make your table runat="server" and then you can access the style attribute in your code behind.

Might I suggest an alternative?

```
<style>
.dbdependant
{
  background: <asp:literal runat="server" id="dbtablecolor" />;
}
</style>
<table class="dbdependant">
```

Then in your code behind:

```
dbtablecolor.Text = dbstring == "pheddv20" ? "white" : "yellow";
```

Ugly, and definitely a hack, but if you put the style/setting in a master page then you can use that same style throughout the application as needed...

Comment: :O ... I've never seen asp:literal in style tag, and would have never thought of it. Interesting.