# Difference between Data Source and Server in connection String

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

Why are some connection strings `Data Source = address; Initial Catalog = dbname;....` while others are `Server=address;database=dbname;...`? What is the difference between using "Data Source" and "Server"?

Answer (score 0):

Please see below link, hope you will easily get answer to your question.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

["Server" vs "Data Source" in connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025055/server-vs-data-source-in-connection-string)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
there is no difference between Server and Data Source as they represent 
the same thing for SQL Server : the full name of the SQL Server instance with 
the syntax "MyComputerName\MyShortInstanceName" , potentially including the 
port used by the SQL Server instance to communicate.
```

---

```
Data Source
-or-
Server
-or-
Address
-or-
Addr
-or-
Network Address
```

the are synonymous

[what is the difference between using data source = and using server = in connection string](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7e3cd9b2-4eed-4103-a07a-5ca2cd33bd21/what-is-the-difference-between-using-data-source-and-using-server-in-connection-string?forum=sqldataaccess)
[“Server” vs “Data Source” in connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025055/server-vs-data-source-in-connection-string)

[SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx)

Comment: How about any other provider like Oracle or TeraData. Which was is standard or which one will work for most of the DB providers? Any references will be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx @ShantanuGupta

Comment: @Nagraj: I know connectionStrings site. I am particularly interested in knowing if there is some standard defined or some sort of guidelines defined which is commonly used between different providers.