# Can't connect to named instance of sql server asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I can't connect via ASP.NET to a named instance of a sql server, that itsn't the default instance.
My servername is NAMEOFSERVER\NAMEOFINSTANCE.

If I try to connect to the default instance of the server, it works.

I use the following connection string:

```
connection_string = "Data Source=" + servername + ";Initial Catalog=" + db_catalog + ";User Id=" + user + ";Password=" + password + ";persist security info=False;Trusted_Connection=No;Connection Timeout=1000"
```

The SQL Server Browser service is running.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Are you able to connect to it via sql management studio ?

Comment: Yes, connecting via sql management studio is working perfectly fine.

Comment: This is not a connection string, this is string concatenation. Debug your code and inspect that `connection_string` contains what you expect it to. You may have a `\n` escape sequence in there, for example.

Comment: I logged connection_string, and it contains what I expected it to. The strange thing is: my other named instance on the same server has got the same connection string (only the name of the instance inside the servername differs) and there the connection works

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your connection string have the pattern above:

```
var connectionString = $"Data Source=myServerName\\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;",
```

Also, make sure you can connect via SQL Management Studio, since instances of the SQL Server can limit access to some users (make sure you connect to the same user name + password you want your app to use).

---

**EDIT**

If the user you are using to connect is not part of a Windows account, please open your instances security configuration and make sure `Mixed Mode` is enabled.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authentication-in-sql-server

Comment: [`Server` and `Data Source` are the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025055/server-vs-data-source-in-connection-string).

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks, I updated my answer. My point was to make sure that the pattern was correct, including the slashes. I also updated with some other tips.

Answer (score -3):

You might want to check if your variable "servername" contains a double backslash. This is needed because backslash is a escape character.

```
connection_string = "Data Source=" + servername.Replace("\\", "\\\\") + ";Initial Catalog=" + db_catalog + ";User Id=" + user + ";Password=" + password + ";persist security info=False;Trusted_Connection=No;Connection Timeout=1000"
```

Comment: My variable contains one backslash:  "nameofmyserver\nameofmyinstance" -  is this a problem?

Comment: Did you try the ConnectionString I added? There the backslash is converted to a double backslash. My suggestion is that it will work when you try it like that.

Comment: You need to escape a backslash when specifying strings in source. You don't need a double backslash in the actual string.