# How to parse a connection string

Tags: asp.net, parsing, connection-string

I need to get the server name from my connection string in my web.config file. How can I parse this value out? I have tried split but it wont allow me to split on a = sign. How do I go about parsing this out?

```
<add name ="Connection" connectionString="server=L\sqlexpress;database=System;User ID=TEst;Password=pass"></add>
```

I need `L\sqlexpress` I know it seems simple but I'm not getting it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there any connection string parser in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804086/is-there-any-connection-string-parser-in-c).

Comment: What do you mean it won't allow you to split on an equal sign character? What is the error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) could be used to initialize an instance with the connectionstring from your web.config. Then you could read the DataSource property

```
string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnectionStringBuilder cns = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(conString);
string dataSource = cns.DataSource;
```