# Pulling text from a string

Tags: c#

I need extract part of a text string (in this case everything after "Data Source =" .

"Data Source=xxxxx"

In VBA, there is a function call Mid()

```
strText = "Data Source=xxxxx"
var = Mid(strText, 12)
```

Is there anything similar in C#?

Comment: It looks like you want to parse an *OleDb connection string*. If that is the case, [consider using the built-in DbConnectionStringBuilder instead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4804086/87698).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String.Substring(Int32)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. **The substring starts at a
>   specified character position and continues to the end of the string.**

```
string strText = "Data Source=xxxxx";
string s = strText.Substring(12);
```

`s` will be `xxxxx`

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/MjZQww)</kbd>.

On your case using [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.IndexOf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method or [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method would be better IMO..

```
string s = strText.Substring(strText.IndexOf('=') + 1);
```

or

```
string s = strText.Split(new []{'='}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You want a substring starting from 12, and outwards:

```
var source = strText.Substring(12);
```

Alternatively, you could start from the index after the `=` (in case you want similar stuff from other settings):

```
var foundValue = strText.Substring(strText.IndexOf("=") + 1);
```

Comment: +1 for `IndexOf`. It makes it clear what it is doing. If you use `var source = strText.Substring(12)`, at least comment it so other people know that it takes a string in the format `Data Source=xxxxx` and gives you `xxxxx`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string originalText = "Data Source = whatever is your text here";
string consText = "Data Source =";

string result = originalText.Substring(originalText.IndexOf(consText) + consText.Length);
```

This will be the simplest and significant way to achieve what you want as you just need to set the constantText you want and get everything after this text.