# Get database name within Up method of Migration

Tags: fluent-migrator

How do I get the name of the database that a migration is operating over from within the `Up` (or `Down`) method of a class that extends `Migration`

```
public class BaseMigration : Migration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        var databaseName = HOW_DO_I_GET_THIS?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can derive the database name from the connection string if you have it specified there. For example, this will work if you're using SQL server:

```cs
public class BaseMigration : Migration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder =
            new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConnectionString);
        var databaseName = builder.InitialCatalog;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, use one of the other available 
[**`System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) implementations:

```cs
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionStringBuilder
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionStringBuilder
```

See [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804086/is-there-any-connection-string-parser-in-c) for more information.