# Parse ConnectionString with = symbol

Tags: c#, parsing, connection-string

I am trying to parse a connection string and extract values to be used in code. The problem is that one of the values in my connections string has an `=` symbol.

Here is the code I have

```
private void Parse(string connectionString)
{
    var components = connectionString.Split(';');
    foreach (var component in components)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(component)) continue;

        var fieldValuePair = component.Trim().Split('=');//Problematic? Don't know how to fix!
        var field = fieldValuePair[0].ToLower();
        var value = fieldValuePair[1];

        switch (field)
        {
            case "url":
                _serverUrl = value;
                break;
            case "authcode":
                _authcode = value;
                break;
            default: throw new InvalidOperationException($"{field} Value is unknown in connection settings");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this code works in all instances except when authcode has an = in it.

So, this connection string does not give the correct details.

```
<add name="ServerAuthCodeString" connectionString="url=https://devunifiedinterface.appstore.com; authCode=mQLw/OWghN0s4jQhBso7o68/KGsLnzwlWux2cnv5QYu=" />
```

What I am getting as output is

```
_authcode = mQLw/OWghN0s4jQhBso7o68/KGsLnzwlWux2cnv5QYu //Missing = at the end
```

What I need is

```
_authcode = mQLw/OWghN0s4jQhBso7o68/KGsLnzwlWux2cnv5QYu=
```

Yes, there is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804086/is-there-any-connection-string-parser-in-c) which talks about connection strings. 
However, the answers still do not appear to resolve the issue with the `=` sign.

For instance, this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804086/is-there-any-connection-string-parser-in-c#comment56154596_15529085) specifically talks about it.

`SqlConnectionStringBuilder` doesn't work for me. If I pass in my connectionString, it complains that keyword url is not vaid.

Comment: Try this => `var fieldValuePair = component.Trim().Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);`

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: Thanks, yes I have seen that question. But, the answers still do not appear to resolve the issue with the = sign. For instance, this comment specifically talks about it. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804086/is-there-any-connection-string-parser-in-c#comment56154596_15529085

SqlConnectionStringBuilder doesn't work for me. If I pass in my connectionString, it complains that keyword url is not vaid.

Comment: @er-sho: Perfect! That worked, thanks much.

Comment: @Alexei, Before marking the answer as duplicate, its better to ask OP that what he/she tried so far to resolve the problem.

Comment: You can also do something like this: `int x = component .IndexOf('='); value = component.Substring(x + 1);`

Comment: @Kanini, glad to hear and welcome :)

Comment: @er-sho: Once the question is re-opened, if you can put your comment as an answer, I will upvote it and mark it as the Accepted answer.

Comment: @Kanini, yes I added my answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify how much splited strings to be return from `Split` function and in your case its `2`.

```
var fieldValuePair = component.Trim().Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);
```

So this will gives you,

- First splitted string at index `0`: `_authcode`
- Second splitted string at index `1`: `mQLw/OWghN0s4jQhBso7o68/KGsLnzwlWux2cnv5QYu=` (including `=`)