# How to get all the column of the current database without specifying the database name in mySql

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a c# project that will list all the column details of a MySql DB.
is there a way that i can query all the column details with out specifying the Db name in the where clause? is it possible for the query to rely only on the Connection string? TIA

Comment: What are you trying to do? Note that you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804086/is-there-any-connection-string-parser-in-c to extract the database name from the connection string.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.

Answer (score -1):

select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.columns

Comment: this will return all the columns of all the Db.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).